# How to cross-compile opencv

Tags: opencv, cross-compiling

I'm trying (with no success) to cross-compile OpenCV on a embedded board.
I followed this: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/crosscompilation/arm_crosscompile_with_cmake.html.

To summarize I installed the cross compilation tools for ARM, the I ran the cmake (providing the proper toolchain file), the make and the make install commands.
I next copied the lib/ include and bin/ directories with the opencv installation in the embedded board.

However, when I try to compile a simple hello world with opencv I get undefined reference to __gnu_thumb1_case_uqi and other similar symbols.
Does anybody faced this problem and know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative approach**

Just take some embedded distro like [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/), [OpenEmbedded](http://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Main_Page) or Debian. They all provide OpenCV.

As I'm mostly experienced in Buildroot, I'd like to point to the newly introduced feature to keep your project separate from BR: http://nightly.buildroot.org/manual.html#outside-br-custom. This will give you a main idea on how to compile your software against BR's OpenCV.